# Obtain all possible Turing Machines from a Universal Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, turing-completeness

Knowing how a **Universal Turing Machines** works and its capabilities, is it possible to obtain the collection *M* = {M0 , M1 , M2 , M3, … } of all possible Turing Machines?

If so, can we prove that a language *L* = {*wj* |*wj* not accepted by *Mj* } is not accepted by the Universal Turing Machine?

Answer (score 1):

Enumerating all the possible TMs is a boring programming exercise. We do not need to use the UTM at all here -- we only have to generate the representation of all TMs and output it, using the chosen encoding of TMs as words.

The UTM does not accept your language $L$ since it accepts another language, namely $\{\langle M,w\rangle \ |\ \mbox{$M$ accepts $w$}\}$.